# How to add a record to a firebase collection using an ionic app?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a record in firebase using my ionic app.

I have already successfully connected to the firebase app because I am using *auth()* to log in users already.

But now, I am not able to create records when I try to add to a collection. Below is my latest code:

```
post(): void {
    console.log('attempting post')
    firebase.firestore().collection('posts').add({
      text: this.text,
      created: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      owner: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
      owner_name: firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName
    }).then((doc) => {
      console.log(doc);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
```

**“attempting post”** is logged to the console, so I’m getting into the *post()* method, but nothing else is appearing in the console, not even an error message.

I have removed the database rules, so anybody can write to the firestore now.
Here is what I have in `environment.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCD9qZV905SELHWvEYoaNqoKKISAO4ddS8",
    authDomain: "feedlyapp-70714.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://feedlyapp-70714.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "feedlyapp-70714",
    storageBucket: "feedlyapp-70714.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1031920662829",
    appId: "1:1031920662829:web:7d5947dd1aed5010c03ba4",
    measurementId: "G-RSDBEJQBLS"
  }
};
```

Feel free to try & write to this DB, because I am having no luck with it so far.

Can someone please tell me what I’m doing wrong, & how it can be resolved?

Also, I've tried to create a collection from the firebase console itself, & it's not allowing me to add records.

Answer (score 0):

There are many documentation and articles that might help you with examples of creating documents with Firebase, using Ionic.

As per the article [Building a Ionic Firebase App step by step](https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/building-a-ionic-firebase-app-step-by-step), this below code sample tries to add posts to a collection, within a collection of people.

```
createPost(value){
   return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
     let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
     this.afs.collection('people').doc(currentUser.uid).collection('posts').add({
       title: value.title,
       description: value.description,
       image: value.image
     })
     .then(
       res => resolve(res),
       err => reject(err)
     )
   })
 }
```

This code is not tested, but I hope it helps you as a starting point.

Besides that, the below articles should provide you with more information and examples of how to achieve the creation of an application with Firebase and Ionic.

- [Building Ionic Apps with Firestore](https://ionicframework.com/blog/building-ionic-apps-with-firestore/)
- [Using Firebase Cloud Firestore with Ionic](https://masteringionic.com/blog/2017-10-22-using-firebase-cloud-firestore-with-ionic/)
- [How to Create a Simple Ionic 4 App with Firebase and AngularFire](https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-firebase-angularfire/)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: I've tried this solution, but behaves the same way as the code in my question. When I execute the code, no error is displayed in the console, but no collection is created in firebase.  I'll try to modify it, & use the links you posted also to see if I can come up with a working piece of code.